# Aw snap Error on javascript in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an asp page in which i use javascript ruzeeborders.js for borders,
in my window.onload function the line:

```
RUZEE.Borders.render();
```

gives 'aw snap' error in google chrome while in other browsers it doesn't show any error,

i want to use RUZEE.Borders.render(); but how to resolve error?

if i remove this line page will show but on including this line gives 'aw snap' error why?

Comment: Hi. It's hard to tell what might be causing the error with just that line of code. It's most likely something else, leading to this line.
Can you please include the preceding code too?

Comment: What happens if you simplify your code to only that one line? Do you still get the error?

Comment: thanks for all help,  i have just coded if its google chrome browser these line will not read and added different code for border in Chrome.